# Java Generics. How to properly extend parameter typed class that extends Generic abstract parameter typed class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have generic abstract superclass **GenericModel** with method that I would like to call in children classes as follow:

```
public abstract class GenericModel<T extends GenericModel> {
    @Transient protected Class<T> entityClass;
    public GenericModel() {
    Class obtainedClass = getClass();
    Type genericSuperclass = null;
    for(;;) {
        genericSuperclass = obtainedClass.getGenericSuperclass();
        if(genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            break;
        }
        obtainedClass = obtainedClass.getSuperclass();
    }
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass_ = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass;
    entityClass = ((Class) ((Class) genericSuperclass_.getActualTypeArguments()[0]));

    // some code

    public List<T> getByCreationUser_Id(Long id) {
        // method body
        return entities;
    }
}
```

I am extending class this class with:

```
public class Insurance extends GenericModel<Insurance> {
     // some code
}
```

And I wanna extend class: `Insurance` with this class as follow:

```
public class Liability extends Insurance {

}
```

and object of `Liability` class I would like call method:
`getByCreationUser_Id()` and instead of list of T I would like to get `List<Liability>` as follow:

```
List<Liability> currentUserInsurances = new Liability().getByCreationUser_Id(1L);
```

Unfortunatelly I am getting an error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Insurance> to List<Liability>`

When I will call same method on Insurance class it works, I am getting an:
`List<Insurance>`

I've already tried declare classes as follow:

```
public class Insurance<T> extends GenericModel<Insurance<T>> {}
public class Liability extends Insurance<Liability> {}
```

But id doesn't work. Compile errors occur.

Please help.

Comment: You already got a good answer, I just want to hint that you might want to avoid raw types, so declare your class as GenericModel<T extends GenericModel<T>>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your `Insurance` class as,

```
public class Insurance<T extends Insurance> extends GenericModel<T> {}
```

And then, your `Liability` class as,

```
public class Liability extends Insurance<Liability> {}
```

Comment: How to initialise java objects for this classes?

Comment: Ok, but I am getting an error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectmyInsurance.models.Insurance` from JPA. Can You help me?

Comment: I think that's related to hibernate framework. And I am not good at it. But it's not related to the Generics. You can ask a new question with the exception trace and the relevant code. Make sure to tag hibernate in that.

Comment: I've added new post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31559837/2794446). Can You tell me is it possible to store the structure/ class declaration from Your answer  in db using jpa persistence?

Comment: It has nothing to do with JPA - it's just that the `genericSuperclass_.getActualTypeArguments()[0]` will return a `TypeVariable` for `Insurance` now - instead of the expected `Class`. I posted the solution in your second question.